# Pass arguments to the function if arguments exist in environment (in R)

Tags: r

Is it possible to pass **arguments** into the function only if **they** exists (assigned) without mentioning the **parameter**? use function's *default values* if **they** do not exist.

```
# function has default value
f <- function(a=0) { print(a) }

# a does not exist yet
f()            # [1] 0 (by default)
f(a)           # Error in print(a) : object 'a' not found

a=1            # a exists now
f(a)           # [1] 1 
f()            # [1] 0
```

I would like:
if `a=1` , then `f(a)` or `f(a=a)`
if `a` does not exist, then `f()`.

I do not want to mention parameter `a`. It can be `a`, `b`, `c` or any *other* which specified for function `f`.

More specifically, I have R markdown (Rmd) report which contains many chunks with many functions and each function has many arguments. I would like to make report more flexible, that users can specify some parameters they want to change. I can pass custom parameters into the Rmd  file and assign them as variables inside the report.
Is it possible to pass these variables into functions without mentioning because there are many different parameters and I do not know what users will use? If it is not possible, what would be the better way to solve it?

Comment: It's better to post your "answer" to your own question as an actual answer below. This site is set up as a question and answer site. It works best when answers are separated from the question and then people can upvote individual answers and you can accept which ever solution you end up using.

Comment: So you want `f(a)` to work even when `a` is not defined outside the function? Your proposed solution seems to involved passing in a list rather than individual parameters. Do you want a list or do you want named parameters? Your final functions look quite different than your sample `f` function.

Comment: It is probably not possible to pass arguments into f() without mentioning them. I guess having one list argument containing all possible parameters for all possible functions will be OK.
Sorry if example confused you. I just wanted to explain the problem in a simple way. I need some universal solution how to pass arguments into many functions if I do not know which arguments will be passed without making changes into the code inside the Rmd report.
f1(args); f2(args); f3(args) ... is probably fine.

Comment: I think `f(a,b,c)` will not work if `a`,`b`,`c` are not assigned. So, I do not know if `a`,`b`,`c` assigned or not, but if yes, I wish that they go into`f(a,b,c)`. If `a` assigned then `f(a)`, if `a`,`b` then `f(a,b)` if non of them are assigned then `f()`.
The version with `args=list()` is just my attempt which works, but maybe there is more correct way to do this. I do not know.

Comment: But how would the be not assigned? Even if you are using markdown parameters, you'll still get some value for the parameters (even if it's NULL). It's unclear to me how it would be undefined. I just can't understand the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: `f <- function(a=1) { print(a) }`  
in Rmd : `f(a) # object 'a' not found`  
I want it works because I do not know if user will use `a` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current solution which works.
I will be also glad to see other ideas and comments.
Is it possible to use ellipsis instead of `args=NULL`?

```
f1 <- function(a=1, b=2, args=NULL) {
     if(!is.null(args)) {
        for (i in seq_along(args)) { 
            assign(names(args[i]), args[[i]]) 
        }
    }
    c = a + b
    return(c)
}

f2 <- function(d="default", args=NULL) {
    if(!is.null(args)) {
        for (i in seq_along(args)) { 
            assign(names(args[i]), args[[i]]) 
        }
    }
    print(d)
}

# if no parameters provided
args <- list()

f1(args=args)    # 3
f2(args=args)    # 'default'

# here will be all custom parameters
args <- list(a=3, b=4, c=0, d="test")

f1(args=args)     # 7
f2(args=args)     # test
```

Ellipsis version. Also needs `args` list parameter.

```
f1 <- function(a=1, b=2,...) {
    dots <- list(...)
    unlist(dots$args)
    if(!is.null(args)) {
        for (i in seq_along(args)) { 
            assign(names(args[i]), args[[i]]) 
        }
    }
    c = a + b
    print(c)
}

# here will be all custom parameters
args <- list(a=3, b=4, c=0, d="test")

f1(args)      # 7
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const args = []

if (a != undefined) {
   args.push(a)
}

if (b != undefined) {
   args.push(b)
}

if (c != undefined) {
   args.push(c)
}

f(...args)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Is there other way without writing this for all existing parameters in all functions? if I use 20 functions in my report and each has 5-10 parameters, the code will be unnecessary huge.

Comment: You might be able to use a helper function that is shared across other functions and does the job. You probably would use rest operator.

```javascript
function f(...args) {
   for (let arg of args) {
      console.log(arg)
   }
}
```

Comment: This answer seems to use javascript but the question was tagged with the R language. As such this won't work.

Comment: Oops. sorry. Missed R in the title!